# mySQLi:: Database is created but table not

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Title explains everything...

Here is my code :

```
$mysqli=new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','') or die('');

$mysqli->query("Create database if not exists myDB");
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE myDB.tableName(RowA,RowB,RowC) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");
$mysqli->close();

//mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

The database is created but unfortunately not the table.

and... btw... what is the difference between `$mysqli->close();` to `mysqli_close($mysqli);`

Comment: That isn't how it's done. See this example http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqltables.php and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-create-tables.htm and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: @Fred -ii- your example is mysql not mysqli

Comment: That's just an syntax "example". You can easily change that, come on. SQL is SQL. Doesn't matter which API you're using.